# Open Shortest Path First (OSPF) Protocol. How it will choose the path?

Tags: networking, router, routing

[Topology example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjRET.png)

I'm using dynamic routing OSPF (Open Shortest Path First). So `Router0` can reach `10.10.10.0/24` via `10.10.11.1` or `10.10.12.1`

How will it determinate which path to use?

Answer (score 0):

First, OSPF will use paths in this order:

- Intra-Area (O)
- Inter-Area (O IA)
- External Type 1 (E1)
- External Type 2 (E2)

If the two paths are of the same type, then OSPF uses cost to determine the best path. Cost is an arbitrary value, often linked to the bandwidth of the links, but it can be manually configured to any value for each link.

All this is detailed in [*RFC 2328, OSPF Version 2*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2328.txt).